# Default attributes

Tags: bash, shell

Good morning folks,

I'd like to edit default attributes of some shell commands.
e.g. if I enter "ls", the shell should then interprete "ls -lth".

Could anyone please help me?
Thanks !
Sonsoles

Answer (score 3):

An alias is the solution:

```
alias ls='ls -lth'
```

You have to store it in your `~/.bashrc` to make it work every time you log in.

In case you some day want to use the default `ls`, you can invoke the default behaviour typing `\ls`.